# Remote server: no such file or directory

Tags: ssh, file-management

Remote server shows some files (.csv) in a particular directory but I cannot open those files or delete them. I have tried using Windows File Manager, FileZilla and also Command Prompt using ssh. When I run the following command

```
sudo rm <file-name>
```

I get the following output

```
no such file or directory
```

But when I run `ls` I can see those files listed
I am completely lost. What are the possible reasons behind this behavior?

Edit:
Running `ls -l` returns the following

```
   total 25
drwxrwxrwx. 2 exemplar deploy    0 Nov 12 23:03 archive
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 exemplar deploy 3685 Mar 11  2021 sample_updates_2021-03-11 00:00:27 +0000.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 exemplar deploy 3685 Mar 13  2021 sample_updates_2021-03-13 00:00:26 +0000.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 exemplar deploy 3670 Mar 16  2021 sample_updates_2021-03-16 00:00:27 +0000.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 exemplar deploy 3685 Mar 17  2021 sample_updates_2021-03-17 00:00:31 +0000.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 exemplar deploy 3670 Apr  3  2021 sample_updates_2021-04-03 00:00:33 +0000.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 exemplar deploy  505 Aug  4 00:08 sample_updates_2021-08-04 00:00:15 +0000.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 exemplar deploy  334 Aug 28 00:08 sample_updates_2021-08-28 00:00:17 +0000.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 exemplar deploy 1422 Sep  1 00:08 sample_updates_2021-09-01 00:00:27 +0000.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 exemplar deploy 1422 Sep  2 00:08 sample_updates_2021-09-02 00:00:19 +0000.csv
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 exemplar deploy  396 Sep 10 00:08 sample_updates_2021-09-10 00:00:19 +0000.csv
```

and this is an XFS file system

Comment: What does `ls -l` actually show about those files? Which directory are they in? What type of filesystem are they in?

Comment: @user1686, I have added the details in the question. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Okay, and how *exactly* are you trying to remove them (via SSH, that is)? The file names seem to have spaces in them; are you dealing with that? And, does `ls -l --quoting=shell` show anything unusual about the names?

Comment: `quoting=shell` giving the same output, except the file names appear inside quotes. I took care of the spaces by putting the whole name in single quotes.

Comment: to remove I used `sudo rm 'sample_updates_2021-03-11 00:00:27 +0000.csv'` which returns `rm: cannot remove ‘sample_updates_2021-03-11 00:00:27 +0000.csv’: No such file or directory`